# How would I only include correlation coefficients above .6 in a correlation matrix?

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to plot only relationships with a correlation coefficient above .6 in a correlation matrix in R. Currently, I am using the package 'corr_test' to run a Pearson Correlation, then I use 'ggcorrplot' to make my matrix. How could I modify my code to only plot correlation coefficients stronger than +.6/-.6?

Below is my current code:

```r
##New Pearson Correlation Script##
#Load in the stuff you dont have
install.packages("psych")
install.packages("ggcorrplot")
#Load it up
library("psych")
library("ggcorrplot")
library("ggplot2")
##Load in your datasets, just fill D1 if one matrix, load D2 as well if 2 matrices
D1 =class
D2 =metab
#Run the correlation
test =corr.test(D1, y = D2, use = "complete")
#r is the correlation matrix 
r = test$r
#p is the p-values
p = test$p

#plot it out 
testplot= ggcorrplot(r, method = "circle" ,lab_size= 0.3, tl.cex = 8, outline.col = "black", tl.col = "black")+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=9),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=9, angle=90))
print(testplot)
```

Click [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z5ueutWZemu2b8Zgx8NvuJKP1bNLb_hN2SxLh-YipWY/edit?usp=sharing) (Google Drive file) for a small dataset of correlation coefficients I have been working with.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean a correlation coefficient above 0.6 *in absolute value*?

Comment: `data(class)` gives `Warning message: In data(class) : data set ‘class’ not found` and the same for `data(metab)`

Comment: I wanted to give my whole code, but the datasheet provided already has the correlations coefficients. I have ran the correlation myself and pulled out the coefficients to be plotted

Comment: And yes, of course in _absolute value_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it's very simple, just set all values below 0.6, in absolute value, to `NA`.

```
r2 <- r    # Save a copy in case you need it later
is.na(r) <- abs(r) < 0.6

#plot it out 
testplot= ggcorrplot(r, method = "circle" ,lab_size= 0.3, tl.cex = 8, outline.col = "black", tl.col = "black")+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=9),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=9, angle=90))
print(testplot)

r <- r2    # reset
rm(r2)     # tidy up
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before you plot, subset based on the absolute value being greater than or equal to 0.6.

`r <- subset(r, abs(r) >= .6)`

Comment: When I try to add this in, I get this error: Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long

Comment: @Haley Odd. Would you mind sharing the output of `r`? Since we don't have the datasets you're using, it's hard to reproduce this error. Or, just use what @Rui suggested, it's just as good.